# Python Selenium, find element by name is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code opens driver and opens website but gives error about:

> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
time.sleep(5)

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("getting started with python")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Please check your selenium version? it must be >=4.3.0, change the line of code to this `driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")` instead of `driver.find_element_by_name("q")`

Comment: I've tried using driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q") too but it said 
NameError: name 'by' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Use ID to find element

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
time.sleep(5)
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id-search-field")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("getting started with python")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

Comment: I've tried it and it said name 'by' is not defined.

Comment: @coderalpaca978 re you import By? 2 line in my example